# Calendar.Read in Application Permissions

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've registered an app on Microsoft Application Registration portal. I added a *Calendar.Read* permission in Application Permissions. How can I get the calendar of the organization by sending the access token in MS Graph API?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNsuH.jpg

I've noticed that Amazon get the calendar event of users' organization by using *Calendar.Read* permission.
This is what I've done:

First, I went to this website to get tenant ID

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?%20client_id=[MyClientID]%20&state=12378%20&redirect_uri=http://localhost
```

I filled in 4 keys in this url: grand_type(value=client_credentials), client_ID, client_secret, resource(app id uri). Then, I got an access token. I insert the access token into graph api. I got an error response code "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed"

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[MyTenantID]/oauth2/token
```

And what can I do with the token I've got in this URL?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: What is the "calendar of the organization"? There isn't a tenant wide calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars.

You need the *Calendars.Read* or *Calendars.ReadWrite* application permission on the Microsoft Graph API.
The permission you have only allows you to read Azure AD info, not Outlook calendars.

Also, the *resource* must be `https://graph.microsoft.com`, since that is what you want to call.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I have already allowed Calendars.Read and Calendars.ReadWrite application permission in Azure AAD. 

I refer to paragraph: service to service access token request
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

but still can't work. Tks!

Comment: Have you attached the access token to the request correctly as a header `Authorization: Bearer tokengoeshere`?

Comment: Yes, l've attached the access token to the request as a header Authorization : bearer [token]